# How to use Electron Webview API with Vue JS and Vue X?

Tags: javascript, webview, vuejs2, electron, vuex

I'm using the [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) boilerplate, and I want to use Electron Webview API in every Vue JS component with VueX.

The problem is that the Webview is only accessible after initialization and therefore methods such as getTitle() are undefined.

Right now my store looks like this.

```
const state = {
  webview: null,
  homePageUrl: 'https://duckduckgo.com/?kac=0&kl=fr-fr&kp=1&kz=-1&kac=-1&k1=-1',
  canGoBack: false,
  canGoForward: false,
  loadInProgress: false
}

const mutations = {
  S_SET_WEBVIEW (state, webview) {
      state.webview = webview
  },
  S_LOAD_URL (state, url) {
    if(state.webview != null) {
      state.webview.loadURL(url)
    }
  },
  S_CAN_GO_BACK (state) {
    if(state.webview != null) {
      state.canGoBack = state.webview.canGoBack()
    }
  },
  S_CAN_GO_FORWARD (state) {
    if(state.webview != null) {
      state.canGoForward = state.webview.canGoForward()
    }
  },
  S_GO_BACK (state) {
    if(state.webview != null && state.canGoBack != false) {
      state.webview.goBack()
    }
  },
  S_GO_FORWARD (state) {
    if(state.webview != null && state.canGoForward != false) {
      state.webview.goForward()
    }
  },
  S_LOADING (state, bool) {
    state.loadInProgress = bool
  }
}

const actions = {
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

And this is how I initialize my variable webview (which is null by default) in my store.

```
mounted() {
      let webview = document.getElementById('search-webview')
      this.$store.commit('S_SET_WEBVIEW', webview)

      // Can go back or forward (or disable btn)
      this.webview.addEventListener('did-navigate', () => {
        this.$store.commit('S_CAN_GO_BACK')
        this.$store.commit('S_CAN_GO_FORWARD')
      })

      // Enable loader (spinner)
      this.webview.addEventListener('did-start-loading', () => {
        this.$store.commit('S_LOADING',true)
      })

      // Disable loader (spinner)
      this.webview.addEventListener('did-stop-loading', () => {
        this.$store.commit('S_LOADING',false)
      })
    }
```

In my other components I would like to get the title of the current page, go back, etc....But it always returns that the method is undefined.

```
this.$store.state.webBrowser.webview.getTitle()
```

Comment: There's a chance that your webview element hasn't been loaded in the mounted() hook, have you tried using a method after everything loaded to pass the data into the store?

Comment: I can't find a hook that comes after mounted. [Vue JS Lifecycle Diagram](https://vuejs.org/images/lifecycle.png)

Comment: beforeUpdate() is called when the dom re renders, though it's probably not the best case.

Comment: The error is slightly different: 
`Error: Cannot call getTitle because the webContents is unavailable. The WebView must be attached to the DOM and the dom-ready event emitted before this method can be called.`

Comment: Well in this case your webview isn't attached the dom when it's been referenced in Vuex so I guess it's not wrong.

Comment: If this is open source I could have a go at reversing the logic in an IoC manner to the component, though I don't know enough about webview to just write out an example that would work here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't think it's necessary, I'll keep looking. I start on Electron and I do tests, nothing very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the life cycle hook `mounted()` found in the Vue JS Lifecycle Diagram to `beforeUpdate()` Resolves the undefined error. Implementing a form of IoC where the component updates the store about it's state with the element would mean that the reference stays within the DOM.